# Insert image element after an element inside a <div>

Tags: jquery, html, image

I am trying to insert an image element after a br tag element which is inside a div.

I am trying with jQuery after as given [here](http://api.jquery.com/after/)

My HTML is like -

```
<div id="toolTipImage" class="ss-content">

  <input checked="checked" id="OutputType2" name="OutputType" type="radio" value="2"> PDF
  <br>
  <input id="OutputType0" name="OutputType" type="radio" value="0"> HTML

</div>
```

And I am trying to insert image

```
var el = { newImg : $("<img>", {class: "profile-image", id: "newImg", src: "path/to/img"}) }

$("toolTipImage").children()[1].after(el.newImg);
```

Please suggest me how I can achieve this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this -

```
(el.newImg).insertAfter($("toolTipImage").children()[1]);
```

Answer (score 0):

You are missing `#` before `toolTipImage` and use `children('br')` instead of `children()[1]`, try this:

```
$("#toolTipImage").children('br').after(el.newImg);
```

OR

```
$("#toolTipImage br").after($("<img>", {class: "profile-image", id: "newImg", src: "path/to/img"}));
```

[**jsFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/manoj_admlab/6CRmz/4/)